How to make multi-threaded build block on a single rule
We have a system for building firmware that uses makefiles...for reasons that I cannot change. Any answers recommending using something better like CMake will be rejected for those reasons.
As part of the build we run a script to generate a Git based version number based on the number of commits in the master branch, and write it to a header file.
This all worked fine for many years until, to speed up builds on another project, I started aliasing make to use the -j option to enable multiple cores/threads in the build process.
The makefile looks like this (not the full makefile):
PHONY: all clean ... premake1

...

$(BUILD_DIR)/versions.h: premake1

premake1:
    "../../EXTERNALS/BuildUtils/GitVersion.sh" "$(BUILD_DIR)"

...

$(BUILD_DIR)/bin/trace.o: trace.c Makefile
    $(CC) $(OPTS) $(INC_OPTS) $(DEF_OPTS) -MM -MG -MP -MF "$(BUILD_DIR)/deps/trace.d" -MT "$(BUILD_DIR)/bin/trace.o" trace.c
    $(CC) $(OPTS) -Wa,-alhms="$(BUILD_DIR)/lst/trace.lst" $(INC_OPTS) $(DEF_OPTS) -c -o "$(BUILD_DIR)/bin/trace.o" trace.c

-include $(DEPENDENCIES)

The dependency file for trace.o looks like:
$(BUILD_DIR)/bin/trace.o: \
 trace.c $(BUILD_DIR)/versions.h \
 ... other files here too ...

versions.h:

What is happening is that the "premake1" rule starts at the same time, and in parallel to, the rule to build trace.o. Invariably both the dependency file for trace.o and trace.o itself are built before versions.h is created.
On clean build, the build fails because versions.h is partial or doesn't exist yet. On repeat builds, the firmware reports a build date that matches the previous build, not the latest build.
What I really want, and I don't understand why make doesn't do this anyway, is for the rule to build trace.o to not even start until the "premake1" rule has completed. Since the rule to make trace.o depends on versions.h, and versions.h depends on "premake1", so the latter rule ought to be allowed to complete, and thus guarantee that versions.h has been generated.
Make has been around a long time, so I doubt that there are bugs in it. Rather, I suspect that there is a feature that I am unaware of, some way to arrange the Makefile so that it all works as I wish.

It's absolutely true that make will not start building a target until all its prerequisites have finished building.  If things build before, it means your prerequisites are wrong.
You write: On clean build, the build fails because versions.h is partial or doesn't exist yet.  That's because I'm assuming, although you don't show this in your example, that the dependencies files are generated as part of the build itself.  This means that on a clean build, the dependencies files don't exist.  That means that there is no statement in the makefile that says that the .o file depends on versions.h... yet.
If you want to use generated output files you generally have to include them as prerequisites directly in the makefile, you can't have them be part of a set of generated dependencies.  If you change your makefile to this:
$(BUILD_DIR)/bin/trace.o: trace.c $(BUILD_DIR)/versions.h

then trace.o will not be started until versions.h is complete.
Second, I assume you're using this premake1 trick to ensure that the rule to build versions.h is run every time you run make.  If you want to do this you need to convince make that there is an actual recipe to build versions.h.  If make doesn't see a recipe, it won't understand that something might have updated that file and it will assume it hasn't changed.
You need to use something like:
$(BUILD_DIR)/versions.h: premake1 ;

Note the semicolon at the end, to represent an empty recipe.

Those are some good tips, thanks. I am currently on something completely different so will have to get back to this later.
